# jQuery function problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I can't execute this jquery function properly. When I click on submit's form, only shows the two first alerts and then the page reloads. So I click again on the form's submit with the page reloaded and then shows the rest of the alerts (beginning by the third one) and then the function works fine.

In conclusion: I need to click on the form's submit two times instead of one to execute the function.

Any idea? Thank you.

**JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("enters script");

$(function () {
    alert("enters jquery function");

    $(".submit").click(function () {
        alert("enters click submit function");

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&date=' + date;
        alert("saved variables");

        if (name == '' || date == '') {
            alert("enters if");

            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        } else {
            alert("enters else");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "join.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    alert("enters success");

                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form method="post" name="form">

    <ul>
        <li>
        Name <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
        </li>

        <li>
        Date <input id="date" name="date" type="date" />
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
        <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
        <span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: check if you have some error in your console please

Comment: A fiddle would be helpfull as always...

Comment: for me works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7Ta8t/

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Have you tried clicking *really* hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you to everybody for your help.

Finally the main problem comes from other part of the code. I was using pjax (https://github.com/thybag/PJAX-Standalone) to replace the form with other html document (in this case page1.html) after doing the mysql insert through "join.php". And I'm not calling the jquery function properly.

Explanation: You begin in page1.html, then click on "Go To Page 2" (This replace the div "content" with the body of page2.html). Then complete the form and submit it. When you click on submit, activates the jquery function (join.php mysql insert inside) and finally replace again the div "content".

Solution (this works):

page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pjax-standalone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    pjax.connect({
            'container': 'content',
            'beforeSend': function(){console.log("before send");},
            'complete': function(){console.log("done!");

                if($("#button_pg_2").length) 
                {
                    $( document ).ready(function() 
                    {
                        $(".submit").click(function() 
                        {
                            var nombre = $("#name").val();
                            var fecha = $("#date").val();
                            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&date=' + date;

                            if(name=='' || date=='')
                            {
                                $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                                $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $.ajax(
                                {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "join.php",
                                    data: dataString,
                                    success: function()
                                    {
                                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                                        replace();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            return false;
                        });
                    });

                }
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function replace()
    {
    pjax.invoke('page1.html', 'content');
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
    This div never changes
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <a href="page2.html" data-pjax="content">Go To Page 2</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="form">

        <ul>
            <li>
            Name <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
            </li>

            <li>
            Date <input id="date" name="date" type="date" />
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div >
            <input type="button" id="button_pg_2" value="submit" class="submit"/>
            <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
            <span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the  event.preventdefault to stop the submission of the page

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: returning false does the same

Comment: In addition to what Arun P Johny said, the problem described by the OP is not that the page gets submitted, he/she has to click the submit button twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using `submit` buttons, they have some default behaviors other than what you add as a event to it.

replaced this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

with:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

this you working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvrm5/)

other than changing the submit button to a regular button, you can fix your code by disabling that default behaviors, adding `onsubmit` to your form node:

```
<form method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <!--your stuff-->
</form>
```

Comment: again the default action of the button click is prevented so how could this help

Comment: @ArunPJohny: actually the default action of the `submit` click is prevented, not `button` click. but the point is if you don't prevent the submit, this would send the all form content to the server, and your page would reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".submit").click(function(){
        alert("entra en la funcion del clic del submit");

```
    var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
    var dataString = 'nombre='+ nombre + '&fecha=' + fecha;
    alert("variables guardadas");

    if(nombre=='' || fecha=='')
    {
    alert("entra en el if");

        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
    }
    else
    {
    alert("entra en el else");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "join.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function()
            {

            alert("entra en el success");

                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                refresca();
            }

            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

});